# Prevent package to be added to yarn.lock

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

I have a package that is added via a github branch, for instance:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "foobar": "https://github.com/foo/bar.git#master"
}
```

How can I prevent foobar to be added to `yarn.lock` since I always want the latest version? I currently have a pre-commit git hook that throws if it's in the staged changes but I'd like to not have to remove it manually every time.

Comment: You can't. There is no feature of yarn that allows this. Generally this is what CI is for